# How can I get blocks of same height in beamer columns and minipage framework?

Tags: beamer, minipage, block

I need help on something that will certainly seem very simple, but I cannot figure out:

I use columns and minipage, in beamer, to have one block on the left and one on the right corner of the page. Then I have a 3rd block at their bottom that is as wide as the page.

Thanks to minipage, the first two blocks have same width. However, I don't know how to "lengthen" the shorter one so they have the same length.

I also have a second question which is why is the 3rd block not the same width has the top ones?

Thanks for your help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}%[T]

\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.5\textheight][c]{\linewidth} 
\begin{block}{block1}
  text
\end{block}
\end{minipage}
\column{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][c]{\linewidth} 
\begin{block}{block2}
\[
\resizebox{25mm}{!}{$\displaystyle\begin{bmatrix}
f_{1} & f_{2} & f_{3}\\ s_{1} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & s_{2} & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$}
\]
\end{block}

\end{minipage}
\end{columns}

\begin{block}{block3}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

- The width of the 3rd block is correct, your first two trespass into the margin as there is not enough space on a single line. You specify both to have `.5\textwidth` which does not leave any space for the separation between them. To solve this, reduce their width and use the `onlytextwidth` option of the `column` environment.
- to make the blocks equally height, place your minipages inside them.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{block1}
          \begin{minipage}[c][0.16\textheight][c]{\linewidth} 
            text
          \end{minipage}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{block2}
            \[
                \begin{bmatrix}
                    f_{1} & f_{2} & f_{3}\\
                    s_{1} & 0 & 0 \\ 
                    0 & s_{2} & 0 
                \end{bmatrix}
            \]
        \end{block}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}

\begin{block}{block3}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]